# Xamarin.Forms app SQL-server database options

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, xamarin, iis-7

I've been studying Xamarin.Forms with goal of building cross-platform mobile app in VisualStudio2015. I've got a perfectly acceptable public facing web site but native app(s) are what the boss thinks we need.

The current web app hosted on IIS 7.5 uses a separate project(DLL) for database access to an on-premises SQL Server 2008 instance. This VStudio project exposes domain objects to the calling ASP.NET webforms by executing various stored procedures using System.Data.SqlClient.

I know building the mobile native app itself with Xamarin.Forms is one part of the challenge but I am **asking here for clarification** about how to approach the database requirements:

**Do I need to create some sort of web service that provides the same CRUD functions required by my current web site?**

[Xamarin documentation lists several options for consuming web services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/consuming/) and the more I search and read about data access I conclude that a callable web service of some type is going to be required for my eventual native mobile app.

**Is this assumption correct?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  You generally want a webservice layer brokering requests between your mobile app (or any remote client) and your DB server.  If you already have all your crud operations in a separate library that is utilized by your website, then a webservice would just be another set of endpoints that rely on the same CRUD library.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I will work toward that.