# How to connect a xamarin forms application to ms sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am an intern and need to build a android and ios application to register worked hours. I use xamarin forms to build this crossplatform application. The application needs to be able to add things to the database wictch is located on the company server (ms sql server).

I have never worked with servers before so i have no idea how i can get data from this database (for the application login) and put data in it (hour registrations).

Webresearch has tought me that i proberly have to create a webservice but at this point i'm not so sure.

Does anyone have any experience or tips about what I should do next? thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin.Forms app SQL-server database options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35634662/xamarin-forms-app-sql-server-database-options)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're an intern, your manager and/or mentor should be giving you more detailed requirements and guidance. You should be asking *them* first, not Stack Overflow.

Yes, you should absolutely create a web service for your application to interact with. You do not want to expose your SQL Server to the internet at large, nor do you want to have to scatter credentials to all your users' devices (or manage different database credentials for each user).

This question likely will be (and should be) closed because it is *far* too broad to be answered in this medium. Entire *books* have been written on this subject.